# text editor for android - how to hook into other applications

Tags: android

Can you please point me into the right direction please.

Basically I would like to code up a text editor application to suite my personal needs (would like it to specially handle some keyboard combination - as shift + x, etc).

The first question - is to how to implement the text editor itself - I know there is a class TextView and I would need to handle OnPress methods (or something like this)
to override inputs (e.g. if the user pressed shift + X - I would like "XXXX" to append to the input). Is TextView where should I start or where a better (at the same time
simple for a novice in the android programming) to start?

My second question is, once I implemented such application - how can I hook/integrate it to/with other applications - such as sms/email applications, etc.

If you can point me to some article/source code on the web - would really appreciate this, because it is quite important to me, it really is.

Cheers.

Comment: This is not a real question, as defined by SO - you should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and then ask one focused question.

Comment: hummm... The app you create would be completely isolated and would not have the necessary permissions to hook into another app, and it is not possible to do so. It is not like with Windows (Android != Windows) where you can hook into the global windows hook and just do whatever is needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is TextView where should I start

Not exactly.

> where a better

`EditText` is usually used to edit text. `EditText` inherits from `TextView`; most of its behaviors are defined on `TextView`.

> how can I hook/integrate it to/with other applications - such as sms/email applications, etc.

That would imply that we could read your mind and know what you mean by "hook/integrate".

If you really mean "how do I replace their editor with mine?", the answer is: you can't, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

> guys, if you don't know how to do this - please don't try to hide it behind a big words - it looks pathetic.

t0mm13b's first comment was accurate.